# Wikidata Query Service returns empty for entity search

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

I used to run the following example taken from the MWAPI page with no problem. However, I tried it today and Yesterday and noticed that no matter what entity you search for, the result is always empty. Does anyone else have the same problem? Any solutions?

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
      bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org";
                      wikibase:api "EntitySearch";
                      mwapi:search "cheese";
                      mwapi:language "en".
      ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item.
      ?num wikibase:apiOrdinal true.
  }
  ?item (wdt:P279|wdt:P31) ?type
} ORDER BY ASC(?num) LIMIT 20
```

Comment: works for me, tested it now

Comment: That's strange, still returns empty for me. I wonder if I have been blacklisted or something ... I tested it on another computer and it DOES return indeed

Comment: clear some cache maybe?

Comment: Yes, clearing cache did it. I feel stupid right now. I think I should delete the question unless you think this is useful to others?

Comment: not sure, I mean you could still provide a small answer which states that sometimes public services return empty results due to maintenance and then a browser caches those result

Comment: Ok, then, I'll answer my own question ... thanks for the quick responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it turns out (thanks to the response from @UninformedUser ) that clearing the browser cache does the trick. Apparently, the WDQS went under some maintenance and that's when I executed my first query which returned empty. All subsequent efforts to run the query resulted in returning the cached status/data which was of course an empty set. Clearing the cache therefore allows you to query the WDQS afresh.